# Making array with increment in LaTeX

Tags: plot, arrays

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
    \edef\s{0,45,...,360}
    \s
\end{document}
```

In LaTeX, I don't know how to make an array start from 0 with increment 45 and end by 360. I try to make code above [I guess it from `\foreach` command] and the result is inappropriate. How to make it?

**EDIT**

I want to make this circle plot:
[image]

First I try to make circle with center (0,0) and radius 3.

Then I make circle with center (3,0) and radius 3*1/(2+sqrt(2)) and rotate it based on sequence angle = {0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360}. I can make it with this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xfp}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.arrows}
\begin{document}
    \def\angle{{0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360}}
    \def\radius{3}
    \edef\s{\fpeval{(1/(2+sqrt(2)))}}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=none, thick] (0,0) circle (\radius);
            \foreach \i in {0,1,...,7}
            {
                \draw[fill=none, thick, rotate around={{\angle[\i]}:(0,0)} ] (\radius,0) circle ( {\radius*\s^1} ) ;
            }
            \draw[fill=none, thick] (0,0) circle ( {\radius*\s^1} ) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

I define sequence angle manually.
`\def\angle{{0,45,90,135,180,225,270,315,360}}`
If the number element of sequence is more, writing element one by one is not good idea.

Now my question: Can we define sequence in latex not manually writing element one by one? I want make sequence start from 0 end by 360 with increment 45.

Comment: What do you mean by an array? What do you want `\s` to be at the end?

Comment: I mean I want to make a sequence 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360.
`\s` in end: I want to display the result of array `\s`

Comment: what do you want to do after making a sequence `0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360` ?

Comment: This related to my `tikz` plot.

Comment: I want to rotate the plot based on that sequence angles.

Comment: So you can describe your situation (e.g. your TikZ plot you want to draw). It's easy to make that array in Python, Asymptote, etc; but not in TikZ/TeX. The command `\foreach` of TikZ has many keys for supporting lists/arrays.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I need to define sequence of angle to plot the circle as above.

Comment: You can use  [`multido`](//ctan.org/pkg/multido): `\multido{\iA=0+45}{8}{\iA}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By use of the polar coordinates and recent `tikz` syntax for drawing circle your MWE can be simplified to:

```
%\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt]{book}
%\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\documentclass[margin=3mm,12pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.arrows   % not used in this MWE
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{\R*(1/(2+sqrt(2)))}

\draw[thick] (0,0)  circle [radius=\R]
                    circle [radius=\r];
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,7}
\draw   (\i*45:\R)  circle [radius=\r];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... looking for something like this?

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}%
\begin{document}
    \edef\s{0,45,...,360}
    \foreach \i in \s {
        \tikz \node[draw, rotate=\i]{\i};
    }
\end{document}
```

[image]

But notice that `\s` is no array; it's the string `0,45,...,360` which is then interpreted by the `\foreach` macro.

Comment: Please see my edited question. I need to define sequence of angle to plot the circle as above.